# local variable in loops (C#)

Tags: c#, loops

I have a compilation error in the following code (in C#).
The error is at each use of userNumber inside the while loop.

In the line with the while I have "The name userNumber does not exist in the current context" and then for each use of userNumber in the if statement I have "cannot use local variable userNumber before it is declared)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Random rand = new System.Random();
    int randomNumber = rand.Next(101);

    Console.WriteLine("give a number between 0 and 100 ?");
    string userNumberstring = Console.ReadLine();

    int userNumber;
    int.TryParse(userNumberstring, out userNumber);

    while (userNumber != randomNumber)
    {
        if (userNumber < 0 || userNumber > 100) {
            Console.WriteLine("out of range");
        }
        else if (userNumber < randomNumber) {
            Console.WriteLine("too small");
        }
        else if (userNumber > randomNumber) {
            Console.WriteLine("too big");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("bug");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("number between 0 and 100 ?");
        string userNumber = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("great");

}
```

Apparently `userNumber` is not recognized inside my while loop. I declared it before the while loop, so could you tell me why it is not valid ?

Thank you

Comment: there is no such variable called `userName` in your posted code

Comment: `userNumber` is declared twice, and `userName` is never declared... Post actual code.

Comment: 1) int userNumber = 0; next you need to read the next number and parse it before looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

1- You're trying to use a local variable `userNumber` before assinging a value for it, this is illegal in C#

2- You're defining two variables with the same name `int userNumber` and `string userNumber`.

To solve this, you can reuse your first variable after assinging a value for it:

```
int userNumber = 0; // assign a value in order to be able to use the variable
int.TryParse(userNumberstring, out userNumber);

while (userNumber != randomNumber)
{
    if (userNumber < 0 || userNumber > 100) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("out of range");
    }
    else if (userNumber < randomNumber) {
        Console.WriteLine("too small");
    }
    else if (userNumber > randomNumber) {
        Console.WriteLine("too big");
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bug");
    }
        Console.WriteLine("number between 0 and 100 ?");
        userNumber = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // reuse variable
    }
Console.WriteLine("great");
```

The above code is simplified, you should consider the unhappy path (Maybe the input is not convertible to integer)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems, the first isn't causing your compile error.  You should *probably* use `int.Parse` in this instance, rather than `int.TryParse`.

The second is you're redeclaring `userNumber` as a `string` at the bottom of the loop.

The reason you're getting the strange message (that it isn't declared) is because it's confusing the compiler and is taking the late declaration over your previous one.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not really match the error you get on compilation. **But** there is an obvious error in your code, that could possibly be the source of your error. You declare `userNumber` as `int` outside of the loop and then inside of the loop declare it again as string. Solve this by assigning the readline to `userNumberString` and reparse the int value:

```
        int userNumber;


        while (userNumber != randomNumber)
        {
            int.TryParse(userNumberstring, out userNumber);

            if (userNumber < 0 || userNumber > 100) {
                Console.WriteLine("out of range");
            }
            else if (userNumber < randomNumber) {
                Console.WriteLine("too small");
            }
            else if (userNumber > randomNumber) {
                Console.WriteLine("too big");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("bug");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("number between 0 and 100 ?");
            userNumberString = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

This code still has the problem, that users can enter anything and the parsing would fail.

Comment: I doubt this will compile as you are referencing the variable before it is assigned.

Comment: @MartinSmith Shouldn't int as a non-nullable value have a default value (I guess 0) ?

Comment: Local variables don't get automatically initialised to the default.